# D3 v4 Bubble Simulation in Object Constructor Not Placing Circles

Tags: d3.js, constructor, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I would like to create D3 bubble charts by placing the creation in an object and calling instances of the object.

Outside of an object the script works well, showing scarttered bubbles, distributed among the canvas.

However, when I attempt to place the script in an object constructor, the forceSimulation function doesn't seem to scattered the bubbles on about the y axis. They simply gather together at the same cy and cx

```
this.forceStrength = 0.03;


  this.width = 940;
  this.height = 600;

  this.center = { x: this.width / 2, y: this.height / 2 };

  this.svg = null;
  this.bubbles = null;
  this.nodes = [];


  this.charge = function(d) {
    return -Math.pow(d.radius, 2.0) * this.forceStrength;
  }

this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .velocityDecay(0.2) //controls the friction at each "tick"
        .force('x', d3.forceX().strength(this.forceStrength).x(this.center.x))
        .force('y', d3.forceY().strength(this.forceStrength).y(this.center.y))
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(this.charge))
        .on('tick',this.ticked)
        .on('end', function() {
    // layout is done
    console.log("end")
  });
```

**UPDATE** Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xjy9s0t/2/) of the full example code

Comment: How do you pass the nodes to the simulation? And how do you use the constructor? Pay attention to the fact that that force is being immediately activated if you create it with `new`.

Comment: I pass nodes using `this.simulation.nodes(this.nodes);` and I have `this.simulation.stop();` after the simulation

Comment: Well, unfortunately this is not enough to help you. A good idea is showing exactly how you are creating the object and passing the data, and a better idea is creating a running example.

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xjy9s0t/2/) of the full example code

Comment: You have two d3.simulation definitions, one on the line 49 and the other on the line 112 of the fiddle, if you remove the second one, it shows the scattered bubbles.